# I want to read line by line from a log file to a php file

Tags: php

So there is this log file that have entries saved in as line by line. Now, I want to read those and display them line by line in a php file. So far, I am able to read the file, but not able to display line by line. My php code is:

```
$file='/var/log/siawa/dashboard/iot.log';

$lastpos = 0;
while (true) {
    usleep(300000); //0.3 s
    clearstatcache(false, $file);
    $len = filesize($file);
    if ($len < $lastpos) {
        //file deleted or reset
        $lastpos = $len;
    }
    elseif ($len > $lastpos) {
        $f = fopen($file, "r");
        if ($f === false)
            die();
        fseek($f, $lastpos);
        while (!feof($f)) {
            $buffer = fgets($f, 4096);
            echo $buffer. "\n";
            flush();
        }
        $lastpos = ftell($f);
        fclose($f);
    }
}
```

These are my entries in the log file:

```
2016-08-17 13:21:28 | INFO: Data on Date: 2016-08-17 12:26:15 already  added
2016-08-17 13:48:46 | INFO: Data on Date: 2016-08-17 12:26:15 already  added
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `echo $buffer. "\n";` -> `echo $buffer. "<br />";`

Comment: look at your html source; the breaks are in there alright. How exactly do you want to see those?

Comment: `echo $buffer. "<br />" . "\n";` < better yet @cmorrissey ;-) as it will output clean html

Comment: no the line break isn't working. I want to show them as they are in the log file one line at a time

Comment: `file_get_contents()` and use `<br>` and `\n`. Asked many times. I told you; look at your html source, the breaks are in there.

Comment: You're welcome. @gaan10

Answer (score 1):

If you looked at your HTML source during your code's execution, you would have seen that the line breaks are very well there.

What you need to do is to [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and output it to screen with `<br>`.

The `\n` isn't enough to show them one line under the other; not on screen anyway.

Add `<br>` and `\n` in order to produce clean HTML.

```
echo $buffer. "<br>" . "\n";
```

Comment: Sidenote: I did not see cmorrissey's comment when I wrote *"look at your html source; the breaks are in there alright."*